# routes asp.net webform default page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am using routes to redirect all url to same page.

I don't want to specify route to every page ,since it's changing by content management system.

I have only 2 pages on the project

1)default.aspx

2)cms.aspx

until today I was using

```
 routes.MapPageRoute("defaultRoute3", "{*value}", "~/cms.aspx");
```

and in cms.aspx page I was using this code to  understand which view to load

```
  string objectCurrentNameUrl = Page.RouteData.Values["value"] as string;

    string[] arrOfParmeters = objectCurrentNameUrl.Split('/');
```

everything was just perfect with one parameter
for example:
mywebsite.com/zone

was redirect to cms.aspx and then I made the split.

The problem start when trying to use antoher parameter on the url

mywebsite.com/zone/114334

the redirect was ok to cms.aspx page but then the routes start sending all javascript,css etc to cms.aspx too.

any idea how to route all url to cms.aspx without route scripts and css

Answer (score 0):

Edited:
This example would help you match only extension-less URLs, and so would keep your static files safe and returned correctly

```
public Route MapPageRoute(
    "defaultRoute3",
    "{folder}/{id}",
    "~/cms.aspx",
    false,
    null,
    new RouteValueDictionary { { "id", "(.*)/([^\./]+)$" }}
)
```

This the full overload that you can use [below overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992946.aspx). Use the constraints parameter to exclude static files

```
public Route MapPageRoute(
    string routeName,
    string routeUrl,
    string physicalFile,
    bool checkPhysicalUrlAccess,
    RouteValueDictionary defaults,
    RouteValueDictionary constraints,
    RouteValueDictionary dataTokens
)
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant code to your answer? Link-only answers usually are not encouraged -- if the link ever changes or goes away, your answer will no longer help.

Comment: -1 Please update to show how this overload would be used to solve the original question.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I haven't worked with regex for a while man.. you had me looking for an hour to find the right one for this! :) .. I hope the update in answer is good enough for you. I couldn't test it for real, so it might need some tweakng

Comment: Thanks for the update. Hint: as far as I'm concerned, if you "haven't worked with regex for a while", then you shouldn't be posting an answer that requires regex. We don't always get a chance to test the code in our answers, but since you haven't worked with regex for a while, it would have been good for you to test it. Post another comment once you've tested it and I'll at least remove the downvote. I may even upvote.

Comment: I have tested the regex of course! I didn't test the route fully to make sure it is perfect. But the regex I know is good!

Comment: @JohnSaunders mr John ... remove the down vote please ... I havent been sleeping

Comment: I still don't see how your answer answers the original question. It's a good answer to "how do I use regular expressions to constrain a route", but that's not what the OP asked.

Comment: @JohnSaunders .. the issue was that his .css and .js files are getting redirected .. the fix below would solve that! ... so only extension-less urls would follow the route

Comment: Thank you :) now i can sleep